# [MS ACCESS]Generate a result column based on the content of other columns?

Tags: ms-access

I want to be able to generate some feedback columns based on the content of other columns, for example. how can I accomplish this in access? Columns Crew, Date, and Trade are predetermined from the source table, Pass/Fail and Cause would be generated with the new addition.

```
**Crew**  l   **Date**     l   **Trade** l **Pass/Fail** l **Cause**
___________________________________________________________________
  123A    l 3/22           l WORK        l Fail          l Crew, Date, Trade
  123B    l ___            l WORK        l Fail          l Crew, Trade
  ____    l ___            l ____        l Pass          l
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `isnull()` to check if any or all 3 columns are `null` and with `iif()` return the result columns:

```
select [Crew], [Date], [Trade],
  iif(isnull([Crew]) and isnull([Date]) and isnull([Trade]), 'Pass', 'Fail') as [Pass/Fail],
  replace(trim(iif(isnull([Crew]), '', 'Crew ') + iif(isnull([Date]), '', 'Date ') + iif(isnull([Trade]), '', 'Trade')), ' ', ',') as [Cause]
from tablename
```

Results:

```
Crew    Date    Trade   Pass/Fail   Cause
123A    3/22    WORK    Fail        Crew,Date,Trade
123B            WORK    Fail        Crew,Trade
                        Pass
```